# How to sync users from Keycloak to MongoDB using Spring Boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, authentication, authorization, keycloak

I am using React with Spring Boot and MongoDB for my application. I have a User entity in my backend, and I need to have the user ID from Keycloak for each user. I am using Keycloak as an authorization server and Spring Boot as a resource server. How can I sync users from Keycloak to MongoDB and get the user ID from Keycloak? How can i make sure that everytime a User registrates using keycloak the same user is persisted in my mongodb document? As i said, i only need the userid. Is there any tool or library that can help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure a sync is the best approach. Assuming you are using OIDC or OAuth2, you would get a token from keycloak. In this token there is an id (maybe called sub) that you can save to DB after successful login (if it doesn't exist already).

Comment: youre right i could do that, but then i would have a request to my backend everytime a user logs in, checking if the user exists or not. If he doesnt exist, then there should be something like a POST request to create the user. Is there a better way?

Comment: I was assuming that you had Spring Security in your resource server and that was what was sending the request to Keycloak. As an alternative: in your flow, I am assuming that you send a redirect URL/URI. This could be your a backend URL with a parameter to redirect to the frontend. This backend URL can be an endpoint that does what you need.